# SQL: Find number of active "events" each month

Tags: sql

#### Background

I have an SQL table that contains all events, with each event containing a unique identifier.

As you can see for some IDs the "event" stretches across multiple months. What I'm trying to find is the number of "active events" per month.

For example event ID:342, is active in both the month of Jan and Feb. So it should count towards both Jan and Feb's final count.

#### Example dataset

| ID | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 342 | 01 Jan 2022 | 12 Feb 2022 |
| 231 | 12 Feb 2022 | 26 Feb 2022 |
| 123 | 20 Jan 2022 | 10 Apr 2022 |

#### Desired output:

| Month | Start Date |
| --- | --- |
| Jan | 2 |
| Feb | 3 |
| Mar | 1 |
| Apr | 1 |

btw: I'm using Alibaba's ODPS SQL and not MySQL or Postgres. So i appreciate if the solution provided could be SQL system agnostic. Thanks!

Comment: OK, so what have you tried?

Comment: I don't know about this product at all (but the OP clearly states that they aren't using MySQL and I suspect aren't using SQL Server, so I've removed those tags), but perhaps the tags [[tag:alibaba-cloud]] and/or [[tag:alibaba-cloud-rds]] are appropriate. I have intentionally not made this edit, as the OP is likely in a better position to tag correctly (or a passing SME).

Comment: Why is there a count of 1 for January? ID 123 also starts in January  - or do you only want to count **full** months?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example is MySQL 8, using a recursive CTE to construct the list of months. It would be more efficient to use a Calendar Table.
If you are not using MySQL you will need to modify the syntax of the query.

> ```
> create table dataset(
> ID int,   Start_date Date,End_date Date);
> insert into dataset values
> (342,'2022-01-01','2022-02-12'),
> (231,'2022-01-12','2022-02-26'),
> (123,'2022-01-20','2022-04-10');
> /*
> Desired output:
> Month Start Date
> Jan   2
> Feb   3
> Mar   1
> Apr   1
> */
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> select 
>   min(month(Start_date)),
>   max(month(End_date))
> from dataset;
> ```
>
> ```
> min(month(Start_date)) | max(month(End_date))
> ---------------------: | -------------------:
>                      1 |                    4
> ```

> ```
> with recursive m as
> (select min(month(Start_date)) mon from dataset
> union all
> select mon + 1 from m
> where mon < (select   max(month(End_date)) from dataset)
> )
> select 
>   mon "month",
>   count(id) "Count"
> from m
> left join dataset 
> on month(Start_date)<= mon
> and month(End_date) >= mon
> group by mon
> order by mon;
> ```
>
> ```
> month | Count
> ----: | ----:
>     1 |     3
>     2 |     3
>     3 |     1
>     4 |     1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=56943b885bab53bce04459cd7bee3523)*